# Can man pass an option to the roff formatter?

Tags: formatting, command-line-arguments, manpage, groff, troff

## SYNOPSIS

### From **man**(1):

#### -l

Format and display local manual files instead of
searching through the system's manual collection.

#### -t

Use *groff -mandoc* to format the manual page to stdout.

### From **groff_tmac**(5):

#### *papersize*

This macro file is already loaded at start-up by **troff** so it
isn't necessary to call it explicitly.  It provides an interface
to set the paper size  on  the  command  line  with  the  option
**-dpaper=***size*.  Possible values for *size* are the same as
the predefined **papersize** values in the DESC file (only
lowercase; see **groff_font**(5) for more) except **a7**–**d7**.
An appended **l** (ell) character denotes landscape orientation.
Examples:  **a4**,  **c3l**,  **letterl**.

Most output drivers need additional command-line switches **-p**
and **-l** to override the default paper length and orientation
as  set in  the driver-specific DESC file.  For example, use the
following for PS output on A4 paper in landscape orientation:

```
sh# groff -Tps -dpaper=a4l -P-pa4 -P-l -ms foo.ms > foo.ps
```

---

## THE PROBLEM

I would like to use these to format local and system man pages to print out, but want to switch the paper size from letter to A4. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything in **man**(1) about  passing options to the underlying **roff** formatter.

Right now I can use

```sh
zcat `man -w man` | groff -tman -dpaper=a4 -P-pa4
```

to format **man**(1) on `stdout`, but that's kind of long and I'd rather have **man** build the pipeline for me if I can. In addition the above pipeline might need changing for more complicated man pages, and while I could use **grog**, even it doesn't detect things like accented characters (for **groff**'s **-k** option), while **man** does (perhaps using locale settings).

Answer (score 1):

The `man` command is typically intended only for searching for and displaying manual pages on a TTY device, *not* for producing typeset and paper printed output.

Depending on the host system, and/or the programs of interest, the a fully typeset printable form of a manual page can sometimes be generated when a program (or the whole system) is compiled.  This is more common for system documents and less common for manual pages though.

Note that depending on which manual pages you are trying to print there may be additional steps required.  Traditionally the following pipeline would be used to cover all the bases:

```
grap $MANFILE | pic | tbl | eqn /usr/pub/eqnchar | troff -tman -Tps | lpr -Pps
```

Your best solution for simplifying your command line would probably be to write a little tiny script which encapsulates what you're doing.  Note that `man -w` might find several different filenames, so you would probably want to print each separately (or maybe only print the first one).

Comment: Shouldn't `man -p gpe -t -Tps | lpr -Pps` be rather equivalent (see also `man --help`)?

Comment: That would depend entirely on the version of `man(1)`.  Most that I personally am familiar with don't have any `--help` option, never mind any `-p` or `-t` options.